# YOLO не видит GPU

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, cuda

Начал изучать nn. При обучении nn kernel крашится:

```
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell. 

Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. 

Click here for more info. 

View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Мною было замечено, что YOLO использует ресурсы CPU для обучения нейронки, и, как я полагаю, именно из-за этого и возникает краш.

CUDNN и CUDA установлены, но yolo не видит видеокарту и не использует ее ресурсы. Как это можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по выводу, у вас просто стоит `CPU` версия `Torch`. На днях аналогичный вопрос тут был, автор сам разобрался, что нужно просто поставить `GPU` версию `Torch`.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, действительно так оказалось. Можешь написать это ответом, я галочку тебе прожму

Comment: Хорошо, что свой ответ написали в итоге, мне некогда )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовал версию Torch для CPU. Скачал версию Torch с CUDA для GPU и пофиксилось